# Can we prove a right continuous real-function has left limits everywhere?

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity, stochastic-processes

càdlàg function is basically a function defined on the real numbers (or a subset) that is everywhere right-continuous and has left limits everywhere.
Can right-continuity be the sufficient condition for a function to be a càdlàg function? In other words can we derive left limit on domain from right continuity?

Comment: This question seems to be interesting.

Comment: The answer is no. $f(x)=sin(1/x)$ if $x<0$ and $f(x)=0$ if $x>0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO.

Consider the function
$$
f(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
\sin(1/x) & \text{if} & x<0, \\
0 & \text{if} & x\ge 0.
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Then $f$ is right continuous everywhere, but has no left limit at $x=0$.

Comment: The OP means not only at a single point.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah This answer is correct and complete. I don't understand your objection.

Comment: Yeah this seems to be the right counterexample. What about the case where you also know that the function is non-decreasing (plus the right continuous condition we had before). Can you prove this then?

Comment: @AmirSoleimani If a function is non-decreasing, then it has left and right limits at all points.